# codeigniter model method not working

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, model, load

Been following a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7RFVKKzcHFY
I watched till 3:50 and it seems its not working...

Note: I have routing working fine and I have called libraries in $autoload and db is working fine just that...

controllers/admin.php

```
<?php
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {

        $this->load->view('admin');
    }

    public function create_user() {

        $this->load->model('user_model');
        echo $this->user_model->create($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
    }

    public function delete_user($user_id) {

        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->user_model->delete($user_id);
    }
}
```

models/user_model.php

```
<?php
class User_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function create($email, $password) {

        return $this->db->insert('user', [
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => $password
        ]);
    }

    public function delete($user_id) {

        $this->db->where(['user_id' => $user_id]);
        return $this->db->delete('user');
    }
}
```

views/admin.php

```
Admin

<form action="<?=site_url('admin/create_user')?>" method="post">
    Email: <input type="email" name="email" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

help...

Comment: help with what?? what is your problem? which of these functions working good for you? and which don't??

Comment: So when I input details and submit into the form it returns a blank page...

Comment: Have you tried loading model in parent construct in controller?

Comment: @KimAlexander yea blank...no 404...

Comment: @mustang83 added it and still returning blank page... lol

Comment: did you check my answer? no messages on the page still?

Comment: Is your model in a sub folder? Have you set your routes etc. if model is in subfolder `$this->load->model('folder/model_name');`

Comment: @mustang83 its in default directory application/models/user_model.php

Comment: @ravextreme: are records been inserted? Seems you are not loading any view in create function and so it showing blank. Try loading view at end of the function. $this->load->view('admin');. If that is the only problem.

Comment: @pritzzz I figured the problem. I was using an older version of PHP which didn't support arrays in `[ ]` format... i changed it to `array()` and is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model you have [] brackets in the insert you can not do it that way. Also when insert you do not need return.

**And in your form action try replacing site url with perferd base_url()**

**Make sure url and form helpers are auto loaded.** please read user guide http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/index.html

echo `$this->user_model->create($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);` not good try var dumping post, and also look into **form validation codeigniter**. I think because you are not running form validation in controller.

Codeigniter 3 is out on github BCIT. https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter

```
<?php

class User_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();
}

public function create($email, $password) {

     $email = $this->input->post('email');
     $password = $this->input->post('password');

     $data = array(
      'email' => $email
      'password' => $password
     );

     $this->db->insert_id();
     $this->db->insert('user', $data);

}

public function delete($user_id) {
    $this->db->where('user_id',  $user_id);
    $this->db->delete('user');
}
}
```

Comment: nice.  seems much cleaner!

Comment: When you use codeigniter the have very simple ways of doing things you can also call uri segments as user id for example if `http://www.example.com/user/update/1` user id would be 1 so segment `$this->uri->segment(3)`, You must set routes though for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

So if you see blank page try just change here:

```
public function create($email, $password) {

    if ($this->db->insert('user', [
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => $password
    ])) {
      return 'User successfully inserted!';
    } else {
      return "Can't insert user: email=".$email."!";
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the class User_model and replaced it with a simple 'echo "test";' seems the page is loading but my method to pass the data to the db is failing...

Comment: so no error messages when call model function? and no outputs?? how could it be possible?

Comment: tried testing if my model works... if i remove my 'create()' and 'delete()' and replace it with just a echo in 'test()' and call it in the URL [link](/admin/test) works fine...

Comment: try to comment `parent::__construct();` in model class

Comment: why `admin/test`? you should test `admin/create_user`

Comment: in the `create_user()` method, i removed all methods and replaced with an `echo 'test function';`, seems to work fine..it prints out 'test function' via the url... some how `$this->load->model('user_model')` is returning a blank page

Answer (score 0):

thanks for trying to help me out! I figured it was my outdated version of PHP... which didn't support `[]` instead of using `array()`
the update is working fine.
Thanks.